# Use "scope" to refer to a book's sections

Tags: meaning, nouns, expressions

I would like to know whether it is correct or not to use the word "scope" to refer to a book's
section, subsection or paragraph. For instance

```
We will address these matters in the next scope.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *scope* of a book would be what the book covers rather than an individual section.

Can you not use

> We will address these matters in the next chapter.

or

> We will address these matters in the next section.